# Slitherlink the second

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

**Find the solution to this slitherlink puzzle that I came up with:**

[image: ![Courtesy of kakuro-online]

This one's even smaller!

Comment: I think His was too, but I'm accepting yours until he posts a description, at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is:

> [image]

First step: start from mid of top row

> [image]

Second step:

> [image]

Third step:

> [image]

Last step: Combine the ends.

One of the solution on my page: that explains possibilities for top 2 and bottom 3's, when i was stuck on second 2:

> [image]

Comment: Can you add a step-by-step explanation?

Comment: @boboquack cant explain much in English:( but for me the boundary was easy, first i stuck at bottom left 3, then top left 2 and finally at second 2. got the solution after solving step by step. start from top mid point to left then go down make three sides for both 3's in bottom row, then avoid the 1 in middle and making sides for both 2's in 4th row, tried solving second row and reach start point. hope my english is understandable

Comment: Wow, that is almost the complete opposite way I did it

Comment: I'm interested to know more about your first step, what exactly let you know that the bottom 3s were like that? In other words, can you go more in depth about your first step?

Comment: for me there was only two possibilities for bottom three, one in answer and one was: top, left and bottom edge. then for both 1's there was two separate edges that was later causing problems for middle rows. actually first i started with wrong one then shifted to this at last. I cant share pictures from my written page

Comment: Actually the bottom 3 was easy for me the most difficult was the 2 in first and second row

Comment: I didn't use guess and check. It's a perfectly valid strategy (especially for 5x5s). I started in the upper right after the obvious stuff (corners)

Answer (score 1):

I Guess, the only solution is :

> [image]

Comment: Can you add a step-by-step explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This solves it uniquely. I've only outlined the steps but can give more detailed explanation if needed.

1. > Started with 3s in corners (drew 2 edges for each).
2. > Using the 2s I worked out the centre square is either bottom or left-top-right. So 2 up-right from it has top-right edges both on or
   >  both off, so the 3 on right has bottom and right on.
3. > The bottom 1 I tried and eliminated (took a while) three edges so the top one is on. Eliminates other edges of the 1 above, makes the center square left-top-right.
4. > The bottom loose edges of 3s have to turn upwards, lose ends of the edge between 1s have to go straight on. Remaining loose ends of 3s go
   >  up (straight on), the 2s in 4th row can only have the second edge on
   >  top.
5. > That determines which 2 edges are on for each of the three 2s on top area.
6. > Continue the loose edge of the 3 near the top right of the grid: up, left, left. Connect both loose edges from right, just follow left and then down.